# Updates error W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: 13.10, updates, software-center, update-manager

For the past week or so, every time I try to update I get the following error message (despite adjusting for nearest server locations...):

```
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix this? *Please be a bit pedantic in any instructions - I'm still fairly new to [using] terminal.*

Answer (score 0):

These are links to packages to Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) which reached its [End of Life](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/07/17/ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2014/). So you can remove these lines from your `/etc/apt/sources.lst` file. If you are still using Ubuntu 13.10, it is better to switch to more recent version such as 14.04 LTS.

Comment: If you find the post helpful you can mark it as the answer